# Nth super odd number

Tags: math

## I have a problem like this that has not been solved, for natural number n, find the nth special odd number in the sequence of special odd numbers

- with odd numbers are known as numbers made up of odd digits and the sum of those digits is also odd.
  The sequence will be written like this : 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 111, 113, 117, .....

please help me thank you very much

I am newbie and i don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: 1st try - walk trough all numbers, check if current is superodd. 2nd try - build superodds step-by-step

Comment: Whenever working with sequences of integers, it helps a lot of the time to take a look at the Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences (oeis.org) to see what you can find out what others have figured out about the sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the sum of odd digits to be odd, the number of digits has to be odd because the digits are always odd.

There are 5 odd digits: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.
If the number has 1 digit, there are 5¹ possibilities.
For 3 digits, there are 5³ possibilities, and so on...

Which means, if you are at the last number of the 3 digit group (i.e. 999), there have been a total of 5¹+5³ special odd numbers until there.

And for the last number of the *k* digit group, there have been n = 5¹+5³+5⁵+...+5^k special odd numbers until then. Now we want to know *k*, so we solve the equation for *k*.

n=5¹+5³+5⁵+...+5^k
25n = 5³+5⁷+...+5^(k+2)
25n – n = 5^(k+2) - 5^1
24n = 5^(k+2) – 5
24n + 5 = 5^(k+2)
k+2 = log(24n + 5) / log(5)
k = log(24n + 5) / log(5) – 2

For example with n=5¹+5³=130 (because the 130th special odd number is 999), we would have k=3. For n=129, k would be around 2.9, but the 129th special odd number still has 3 digits.

So to get the number of digits for the nth special odd number, we round the result up: k = ceil(log(24n + 5) / log(5)) – 2

And to get the total number of special odd numbers for all *m* digit groups with m < k and k being an odd number, you can use
t = (5^k - 5) / 24 = 5¹ + 5³ + ... + 5^(k-2)
which also follows from the equation above.

The index in that *k* digit group for any *n* is then i = n-t-1.
For example 111 (n=6) has the index 0 in the 3 digit group, 113 (n=7) the index 1 and so on.

Now we know the number of digits and the index.
Let’s imagine that the index we have is actually in base 5.
So for k=3 we have

index=0 => 000
index=1 => 001
...
index=4 => 004
index=5 => 010
index=6 => 011
...
index=5³-1 => 444 (last index for that digit group)

It is quite obvious now, that we only have to map 0 to 1, 1 to 3, 2 to 5, and so on. And that is basically what the for loop does in the Python code.

After the mapping is done, we have our nth special odd number.

```py
def special_odd(n):
    # get k: number of digits
    # we do not use the logarithm, because of floating errors
    possibilities = 24*n + 5
    k, p = 1, 5
    while p < possibilities:
        k += 2
        p *= 25
    k -= 2
    
    previous_possibilities = (5**k - 5) // 24
    index_for_k_digits = n - previous_possibilities - 1 # index starting with 0
    odds = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
    num = 0
    
    for i in range(k):
        index_for_k_digits, rem = divmod(index_for_k_digits, 5)
        num += 10**i * odds[rem]
    
    return num
```